# Is there any movie with a laugh track?

Tags: production, soundtrack, comedy

I understand laugh track (canned laughter) is mostly added to sitcoms citing reasons that it induces laughter (or laughter at the right moment) in the viewer as he/she is not with a crowd.
But just curious, has there been any movie made with a laugh track?

Comment: Related https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/46294/why-are-laugh-tracks-only-used-in-tv-series-but-not-in-movies

Comment: Scott Pilgrim vs The World has a brief section with a laugh track - but that's deliberately intending to ape a TV sitcom.

Comment: As does Natural Born Killers

Comment: If I recall correctly, Requiem For A Dream also had similar sections

Comment: "*The DVDs of Epic Movie and Date Movie actually come with an optional laugh track."*